# How to make lock wait until it is freed?

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine

I am using Lock to access a queue, but one of the cases seems to never execute the block of code inside of lock
I have one thread that will execute the following code every few seconds

```
lock(queueLock){ 
    while(queue.Count > 0){
        doSomething(queue.Dequeue());
    }
}
```

And another thread that will execute the following code depending on I/O(Not determined by time interval):

```
lock(queueLock){
   queue.Enqueue(input);       
}
```

This second one never getes to execute the code inside the lock. I already tried to use the debugger or prints, but this just seems to run and on the threads window of the VS debugger it looks like the thread just died after trying to acquire the lock while no other thread was even using this queue.

I am not using .net I am programming on unity, but in this case I am not using anything unity specific besides the update function.

Comment: Share complete code sample. It's possible to identify issue in given snippet.

Comment: http://dotnetpattern.com/csharp-concurrentqueue

Comment: If you're only locking because of the queue, you know there is a thread safe queue that don't need to use lock, right? [ConcurrentQueue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: or my favorite, BlockingCollection https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @pm100 why would the first call block if the queue is empty? Wouldn't the `while` not execute and the lock be freed?

Comment: @Magnetron I didn't knew it, I will try it now and see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: So I can't use ConcurrentQueue, because it needs .NET Framework 4.6, and as I said before it is on Unity, so I don't have access to the .NET Framework.

Comment: Take a look here: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/139262/blocking-queue-in-unity

Answer (score 0):

Try using the thread-safe [ConcurrentQueue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) without locks.

Comment: So I can't use ConcurrentQueue, because it needs .NET Framework 4.6, and as I said before it is on Unity, so I don't have access to the .NET Framework.

Comment: here's the source: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/src/Internal/ConcurrentQueue.cs

Have you ensured a thread is calling the second block of code?

Answer (score 0):

in the end, the problem wasn't with lock, actually just a line of code before the lock for the enqueue, I was casting e from json to another class and ended up throwing an exception that the unity wasn't showing me, but as I never worked with multithread in c# before I ended up looking on the wrong place.